# getting values by time difference in SQL

Tags: sql

I want to get the difference of two values within a time frame.

so I have a table like this

Data Table

```
TimeStamp        DataValue
2010-06-01        21
2010-06-03        33
2010-06-05        44
```

So I want to first get all data over the last month which I can do with something like.

```
([TimeStamp] < GETDATE()-0 and ([TimeStamp] > GETDATE()-31)
```

But I want to see how much value added on over the course of the month. So it started at 21 and went to 44. So I would expect this example to to return 23 (as in 44-21).

How would I build a query like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this works in MySQL. I can't promise for other databases.

```
SELECT MAX(DataValue) - MIN(DataValue) FROM TABLE
WHERE ([TimeStamp] < GETDATE()-0
AND ([TimeStamp] > GETDATE()-31)
```

Comment: This should work, but only if you have the lowest value when the month starts, and the highest value at the end of the month.

Comment: I was trying to make this too complicated. Thinking I would somehow have to get the first value alias it and all.

Comment: That would be another way of doing it. And that way might be necessary if the values could go either up or down. I assumed from your language in the question that they could only increase over time.